# Can you override (write) the nest ambient_temperature?

Tags: nest, nest-api

The permission write is there but the description says read. I want to set the temperature IN my upstair room from wireless arduino board with temp sensor and override the nest ambiant downstairs temp?

[Nest reference api url](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/api-overview#ambienttemperaturef)

Answer (score 2):

No. Although the field is part of the "Thermostat read/write" permission, it is "Read Only" as per the [API Reference](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference)

Answer (score 0):

The docs say "You can read this data value when these permissions are selected:" which means that you can read that value if either permission were selected. It doesn't mean that you can write to it.

Comment: They don't override that state, they are changing the set point.